# history.js stops firing statechange event after pressing back button 2 times

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, navbar, history.js

One of my customer has a lot of webistes based on lots of CMS (Wordpress, Drupal and so on). He wanted a generic directory, where professionals can register and share information. It is "generic", as it can be installed on any website (declined according to the website's business).

I developed it inside an iframe, as this can be installed on any CMS, and there were other good reasons to do it this way (CSS, SEO...). But as iframe-browsing is transparent for the navigation bar, I needed to do some tricks to allow visitors to copy/paste professionals's urls, share and fav them. I used history.js to update the navbar's URL, and when direct-accessing the iframe I redirect the user to the right "main website"'s page.

But my problem come when clicking the "back" button. For some reasons, the "`statechange`" event is not properly fired when clicking "back" a second time.

### I developed a demo, you can see [my problem live here](http://so.ocarina.fr/test/main.html), and you can [download it here](http://so.ocarina.fr/test.zip).

As you can see on the log div, when you click B and C, you'll get:

```
Push: /a.html
Push: /b.html
statechange trigered
Push: /c.html
statechange trigered
```

If you go back once, you'll get:

```
statechange trigered
Pop: /b.html
```

And if you go back a second time, you'll get:

```
Push: /c.html
statechange trigered
```

Instead of:

```
statechange trigered
Pop: /a.html
```

So my question:

> What is going on here ?

<kbd>main.html</kbd>

```
<iframe id="my-test" src="a.html" width="500" height="500"></iframe>

<div id="log"></div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-browser/0.0.6/jquery.browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="history.js/scripts/bundled/html4+html5/jquery.history.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var test_url = 'http://so.ocarina.fr/test';

    // used to avoid listening events trigered by the script itself
    var manual_state_change = true;

    // used to avoid pushing the previous page
    var is_back = false;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#my-test').load(function () {

            // when iframe has loaded, we replace the navbar's url by
            // the one from iframe's source.

            if (!window.is_back) {
                window.manual_state_change = false;

                var History = window.History;
                if (History.enabled) {

                    var url = $('#my-test').get(0).contentWindow.location.href;
                    if (url.indexOf('blank') > 0) {
                        return;
                    }
                    if (url.indexOf('test') > 0) {
                        url = url.substring(url.indexOf('test') + 4);
                        if (url.length === 0) {
                            url = '/';
                        }
                    }

                    $('#log').append('Push: ' + url + '<br/>');

                    var title = $("#my-test").contents().find("title").html();
                    document.title = title;
                    History.pushState({url: decodeURIComponent(url + '')}, title, window.test_url + decodeURIComponent(url + ''));

                    window.manual_state_change = true;
                }
            }
            window.is_back = false;

        }).trigger('load'); // triggered once to replace main.html by a.html

        var History = window.History;
        if (History.enabled) {
            History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function () {

                // if user clicks back, we should change the iframe's location
                // to the backward url from history stack.

                $('#log').append('statechange trigered <br/>');

                if (window.manual_state_change === true) {
                    window.manual_state_change = false;
                    var state = History.getState();
                    var url = state.data.url;
                    $('#log').append('Pop: ' + url + '<br/>');
                    window.is_back = true;
                    $('#my-test').attr('src', window.test_url + url);
                    $('#my-test')[0].contentWindow.location = window.test_url + url;
                    window.manual_state_change = true;
                }

            });
        }

    });

</script>
```

<kbd>a.html</kbd>

```
<title>Test A</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
    if (top.location === self.location) {
        window.location = 'main.html';
    }
</script>

<div id="content">

    <p>This is test A</p>

    <a href="b.html">Go to test B</a>

</div>
```

<kbd>b.html</kbd>

```
<title>Test B</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
    if (top.location === self.location) {
        window.location = 'main.html';
    }
</script>

<div id="content">

    <p>This is test B</p>

    <a href="c.html">Go to test C</a>

</div>
```

<kbd>c.html</kbd>

```
<title>Test C</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
    if (top.location === self.location) {
        window.location = 'main.html';
    }
</script>

<div id="content">

    <p>This is test C</p>

    <p>Go back to A using your backward button...</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found my mistake: **when clicking on my iframe's links, browser already add an entry to the history**, so I shouldn't add an entry using `pushState`, but simply replace the current history entry using `replaceState`.

Bonus: we don't need to handle statechange, browser does anything as naturally as usual. Cool!

### See the working demo [here](http://so.ocarina.fr/test2/main.html).

My code becomes:

```
<iframe id="my-test" src="a.html" width="500" height="500"></iframe>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-browser/0.0.6/jquery.browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="history.js/scripts/bundled/html4+html5/jquery.history.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  var test_url = 'http://so.ocarina.fr/test2';

  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#my-test').load(function () {

        // when iframe has loaded, we replace the navbar's url by
        // the one from iframe's source.

        var History = window.History;
        if (History.enabled) {

            var url = $('#my-test').get(0).contentWindow.location.href;
            if (url.indexOf('blank') > 0) {
                return;
            }
            if (url.indexOf('test') > 0) {
                url = url.substring(url.indexOf('test2') + 5);
                if (url.length === 0) {
                    url = '/';
                }
            }

            var title = $("#my-test").contents().find("title").html();
            document.title = title;
            History.replaceState({}, title, window.test_url + decodeURIComponent(url + '')); // YES!

        }

    }).trigger('load'); // triggered once to replace main.html by a.html

});


</script>
```